# Trouble with VB.NET Liang-Barsky implementation

Tags: vb.net, 2d, collision-detection, line-segment

After some research, I've decided to use the **Liang-Barsky** line clipping algorithm in my 2D game. Google did not deliver on any VB.NET implementations of this algorithm but plenty C/++ ones. Therefore, as I have knowledge in C++, decided to [port one found on Skytopia](http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/clipping.html) over to VB.Net. Unfortunately, it does not work with:

```
Public Class PhysicsObject
    Public Function CollideRay(ByVal p0 As Point, ByVal p1 As Point, ByRef clip0 As Point, ByRef clip1 As Point) As Boolean
        Dim t0 As Double = 0.0
        Dim t1 As Double = 1.0
        Dim xdelta As Double = p1.X - p0.X
        Dim ydelta As Double = p1.Y - p0.Y
        Dim p, q, r As Double

        For edge = 0 To 3
            ' Traverse through left, right, bottom, top edges
            If (edge = 0) Then
                p = -xdelta
                q = -(AABB.Left - p0.X)
            ElseIf (edge = 1) Then
                p = xdelta
                q = (AABB.Right - p0.X)
            ElseIf (edge = 2) Then
                p = -ydelta
                q = -(AABB.Bottom - p0.Y)
            ElseIf (edge = 3) Then
                p = ydelta
                q = (AABB.Top - p0.Y)
            End If

            r = q / p

            If p = 0 And q < 0 Then Return False ' Don't draw line at all. (parallel line outside)

            If p < 0 Then
                If r > t1 Then
                    Return False ' Don't draw line at all.
                ElseIf r > t0 Then
                    t0 = r ' Line is clipped!
                End If
            ElseIf p > 0 Then
                If r < t0 Then
                    Return False ' Don't draw line at all.
                ElseIf r < t1 Then
                    t1 = r ' Line is clipped!
                End If
            End If
        Next

        clip0.X = p0.X + t0 * xdelta
        clip0.Y = p0.Y + t0 * ydelta
        clip1.X = p0.X + t1 * xdelta
        clip1.Y = p0.Y + t1 * ydelta

        Return True        ' (clipped) line is drawn
    End Function

    Public AABB As Rectangle
End Class
```

I'm using the class/method like:

```
    Dim testPhysics As PhysicsObject = New PhysicsObject
    testPhysics.AABB = New Rectangle(30, 30, 20, 20)

    Dim p0, p1 As Point
    p0 = New Point(0, 0)
    p1 = New Point(120, 120)

    Dim clip0, clip1 As Point
    clip0 = New Point(-1, -1)
    clip1 = New Point(-1, -1)

    GlobalRenderer.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LimeGreen, p0, p1)

    If testPhysics.CollideRay(p0, p1, clip0, clip1) Then
        GlobalRenderer.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Magenta, clip0, clip1)
    End If
```

However, the *CollideRay* method fails on its 3rd edge iteration (edge = 3), r < t0, therefore the function returns false.

I'm wondering if anyone can spot some issue with my *CollideRay* function which would result in this behaviour, because I'm well and truly stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code assumes a different coordinate system, note that topEdge is *larger* than bottomEdge in the linked web page.  Your test works with normal graphics coordinates where Bottom is larger than Top.  You have to swap the bottom and top arguments.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'll try out tomorrow and let you know how it works out :) EDIT: works perfectly now, accepted!